# How apply ellipsis to title in Material UI CardHeader

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `Material-UI` and I'm trying to apply ellipsis to the underlying Typography component in `CardHeader`, but passing `noWrap` into `titleTypographyProps` doesn't seem to work.

Do I need to override `CardHeader` somehow? I tried setting `max-width: 100%` on both `CardHeader` and the underlying `Typography` component with no luck.

Demo

[image: Edit determined-archimedes-p8pvj]

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what actually you want?

Comment: I want to add ellipsis on the title in CardHeader so that it'll work the same way as with the Tyography component shown in the example. I'm wondering why the noWrap property I'm passing to CardHeader via titleTypographyProps  isn't taking effect.

If you try to resize the width in the example you'll see ellipsis is applied to the Typography component, but not in the CardHeader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with `MuiCardHeader-content` flex. You need to give it a width so that it may show itself inside its parent.

```
.MuiCardHeader-content {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. Here's an example with working code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-vaughan-6xjlx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: if you're using an icon (avatar) on the card, it doesn't work, as the 100% width overflows the available space

Comment: Where do I need to place this?

Answer (score 2):

In order to expand the answer by @Awais, if you override the content CSS class for the header with this:

```
content {
    display: contents
}
```

It will make your header handle the ellipsis properly even if you use a icon.

Comment: I tried this, but now the header title placement is all wonky...  It's all the way in the top left corner and even behind the avatar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with flex, due to having an `avatar` and an `action icon`. Therefore, after trying a different approach this is what worked for me:

Try adding this code to the `CardHeader` component

```
    sx={{
      '& .MuiCardHeader-content': {
          display: 'block',
          overflow: 'hidden',
       },
    }}

    titleTypographyProps={{
      noWrap: true,
      textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    }}
```